# Angular ng-click not showing anything

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to load view to a div on a click event and it not giving nothing . 
"SkillCtrl"

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('SkillCtrl', function ($scope,$location) {
this.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma',

];
 $scope.changeView = function(view)
    {
        console.log($scope);
        $location.path(view); // path not hash
    }
});
```

and view file

```
<div class="container-narrow" id="experince" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="SkillCtrl">
<ul class="clearfix">
  <div ng-click = 'changeView("skill_chart")'>Skills</div>
</ul>
<div >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you load views to html in angular.If that is what you are trying to achieve,you should use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive to load an external html template inside div.
`$location.path` actually changes the rendering content for your `ng-view` directive.

If you want to change the rendered content of ng-view you need to define the corresponding route while configuring your `$routeProvider` service.Please be a little more specific as to what you want to achieve, so that we can give you more relevant solutions.

Edit: Heres how you can load a content to div on click.

```
<span ng-click="change('path_to_your_view')">Click To Change</span>
<div ng-include="view"></div>
```

For your controller:

```
$scope.change=function(path){
   $scope.view=path;
}
```

Comment: i'm new to angular and i use code in the internet. problem is according to my code when i click the div it should go to the controller but i think it not happening. c

Comment: Then you need `ng-include`. Kindly go through its documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude . You need to use it along with ng-click on some other element.In case you are not able to do it. Then you can ask for further help.

Comment: @learnwhat go through some proper tutorials instead of just `grab code from internet`

Comment: @abdul I did load content on to div using ng-include but i need to load that on click event can you help me with that?.

Comment: @charlietfl can u suggest me a popper tutorial for angular js it is a great help.

Comment: problem is  Click To Change can't be click

Answer (score 1):

Angular path requires a leading `/`

Try:

```
 $location.path('/' + view);
```